# nested JSON extraction in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I've managed to convert the json below to a dataframe, but the nested lists are more complex ie the one in lineups that includes player event, player id and shirt number. They don't easily merge with the rest of the data due too being nested and all that data is nested in one column in the dataframe.

For example I have managed to extract all the data into a dataframe with columns but lineups contains all the nested data in one cell. I'm struggling to figure out how to unnest all the data so it still reflects in one row in the dataframe in the match associated with.

```
{
    "data": {
        "GoalCount_2hg": 1,
        "HTGoalCount": 2,
        "attacks_recorded": 1,
        "attendance": 31830,
        "avg_potential": 3.04,
        "awayGoalCount": 1,
        "awayGoals": [
            "85"
        ],
        "awayID": 218,
        "away_image": "teams/england-brentford-fc.png",
        "away_name": "Brentford",
        "away_ppg": 1.16,
        "away_url": "/clubs/brentford-fc-218",
        "homeID": 108,
        "home_image": "teams/england-leicester-city-fc.png",
        "home_name": "Leicester City",
        "home_ppg": 1.79,
        "home_url": "/clubs/leicester-city-fc-108",
        "ht_goals_team_a": 2,
        "ht_goals_team_b": 0,
        "id": 1308560,
        "lineups": {
            "team_a": [
                {
                    "player_events": [],
                    "player_id": 3212,
                    "shirt_number": 1
                },
                {
                    "player_events": [],
                    "player_id": 3219,
                    "shirt_number": 18
                },
                {
                    "player_events": [
                        {
                            "event_time": "20",
                            "event_type": "Goal"
                        }
                    ],
                    "player_id": 21538,
                    "shirt_number": 27
                },
                {
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ? what is your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to extract the team a and team b line ups so that all players are in one row in a dataframe along with the rest of the data. So I have a dataframe which as all the other data in columns, but the lineups are nested in one column. I would like it all in one dataframe and in the same row, each dictionary of the other data is a column.

Answer (score 0):

Using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to parse and [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) to merge:

```
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd


main = pd.json_normalize(data=data["data"]).drop(columns=["lineups.team_a", "lineups.team_b"]).explode("awayGoals")

team_a = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["data"],
    meta=["id", ["lineups", "team_a", "player_id"], ["lineups", "team_a", "shirt_number"]],
    record_path=["lineups", "team_a", "player_events"]
)

team_b = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["data"],
    meta=["id", ["lineups", "team_b", "player_id"], ["lineups", "team_b", "shirt_number"]],
    record_path=["lineups", "team_b", "player_events"]
)

dfs = [main, team_a, team_b]
df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="id"), dfs)
df_final.columns = df_final.columns.str.split(pat=".", n=1).str[-1]
print(df_final)
```